# How to get the edittext variable: java android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to get different variables for the editText which i coded with java (LOOP) not XML.

I am working on a project where user is asked how many courses did you offer?, if 10 the EditText will appear 10 times. But I want to get the variable name of each editText and its value. I am only getting the value of the last one.

```
public class CourseEnter extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextInputLayout noOfCourse, textInputLayout,

courseCreditLoadInputLayout, courseScoreInputLayout;

private TextInputLayout dropDown;
private int i;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;

private TextInputEditText courseCode, courseTitle, courseCreditLoad, courseScore;
String[] update;

ArrayList<String> courseTitles= new ArrayList<String>();//not used for now
ArrayList<String> courseCodes= new ArrayList<String>();//not used for now
ArrayList<String> courseLoads= new ArrayList<String>();//not used for now
ArrayList<String> courseScores= new ArrayList<String>();//not used for now

String courseTitleId;
private Button buttonNext;
private Button button;
private TextInputLayout courseCodeInputLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_enter);
    String[] SEMESTERS = new String[]{"First Semester", "Second Semester"};
    String[]   LEVELS = new String[] {"100 Level", "200 Level", "300 Level", "400 Level","500 Level", "600 Level"
            ,"700 Level"};
    dropDown = findViewById(R.id.dropdownM);
    courser = findViewById(R.id.coureser);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_list,LEVELS);
    AutoCompleteTextView editTextFilledExposedDropdown =
            findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteViewForLevel);
    editTextFilledExposedDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSemester = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_list, SEMESTERS);
    AutoCompleteTextView editSEMESTER =
            findViewById(R.id.semester2);
    editSEMESTER.setAdapter(adapterSemester);
    buttonNext = findViewById(R.id.secondButton);


    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            courseColumn();

        }
    });

}

void courseColumn() {
    noOfCourse = findViewById(R.id.numberOfCourses);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(noOfCourse.getEditText().getText().toString())) {
        String generateCourse = noOfCourse.getEditText().getText().toString();
        int courseToInt = Integer.parseInt(generateCourse);


        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);


        for (i = 1; i <= courseToInt; i++) {
            textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
            courseTitle = new TextInputEditText(this);
            textInputLayout.setHelperText("Enter Course Title for Course " + i + ":");
            textInputLayout.setHelperTextEnabled(true);
            courseTitle.setId(i);
            textInputLayout.setHintTextColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
            //courseTitle.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
            courseTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            String a = Integer.toString(i);
            courseTitleId = "courseTitle" + a;
            // update[i]=courseTitleId;

            //For Course Code

            courseCodeInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
            courseCode = new TextInputEditText(this);
            courseCodeInputLayout.setHelperText("Enter Course Code for Course " + i + ":");
            courseCodeInputLayout.setHelperTextEnabled(true);
            courseCode.setAllCaps(true);

            // lastly added
            courseCode.setId(i);


            //for Course Credit Load
            courseCreditLoadInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
            courseCreditLoad = new TextInputEditText(this);
            courseCreditLoadInputLayout.setHelperText("Enter Course Credit 
            or Unit for Course " + i + " only numbers" + ":");

            courseCreditLoadInputLayout.setHelperTextEnabled(true);

            courseCreditLoad.setAllCaps(true);
            courseCreditLoad.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            courseCreditLoadInputLayout.setCounterEnabled(true);
            courseCreditLoadInputLayout.setCounterMaxLength(1);

            //for Score
            courseScoreInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
            courseScore = new TextInputEditText(this);
            courseScoreInputLayout.setHelperText("Enter Score for Course " 
            + i + " only numbers" + ":");
            courseScoreInputLayout.setHelperTextEnabled(true);
            courseScore.setAllCaps(true);
            courseScore.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            courseScoreInputLayout.setCounterEnabled(true);
            courseScoreInputLayout.setCounterMaxLength(3);

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            for (int bt = 1; bt <= i; bt++) {
                btn.setText("STEP " + bt);
                btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            //toString methods of all the inputs
           String courseT= courseTitle.getText().toString();
            String courseC= courseCode.getText().toString();
            String courseL= courseCreditLoad.getText().toString();
            String courseS= courseScore.getText().toString();
            courseTitle.setLayoutParams(new 

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            linearLayout.addView(btn);

            linearLayout.addView(textInputLayout);
            linearLayout.addView(courseTitle);
            linearLayout.addView(courseCodeInputLayout);
            linearLayout.addView(courseCode);
            linearLayout.addView(courseCreditLoadInputLayout);
            linearLayout.addView(courseCreditLoad);
            linearLayout.addView(courseScoreInputLayout);
            linearLayout.addView(courseScore);


            //remeber to change the button id and name=
            button = new Button(this);
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setEnabled(true);
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            button.setText("Proceed");
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(CourseEnter.this);
                    dialog.setTitle("GUIDE FROM VICTORHEZ!!!");
                    dialog.setMessage("For you to save your result, you 
  must fill all fields provided above");
                   dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                   dialog.setCancelable(false);
                   dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, 
     "OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoga, int 
     which) {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                           proceedMethod();
                       }
                   });
                    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "GO 
       BACK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoga, int 
           which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                   dialog.show();



                }
            });

        }
        linearLayout.addView(button);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Field: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        noOfCourse.setError("ENTER FIELD");

    }

  }

  private void proceedMethod() {

  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(courseTitle.getText()))
 {
   textInputLayout.setError("Error: Enter Field");
   }
  else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(courseCode.getText()))
 {
 courseCodeInputLayout.setError("Error: Enter Field");
 }
else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(courseCreditLoad.getText()))
{
courseCreditLoadInputLayout.setError("Error: Enter Field");
}
else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(courseScore.getText()))
{
courseScoreInputLayout.setError("Error: Enter Field");
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(CourseEnter.this,"VICTORHEZ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}


}
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. ALL CAPs is equivalent to shouting on this (and most other) site. Instead, use standard case, and please try to tell the details of your problem as per the [ask] and the [help]

Answer (score 0):

Either you store it in an array,map, or setTag.
You just created the elements but has no way of accessing them again.
It depends on how you're planning to use the elements. 
If you can add more detail to the question, then maybe we can set the best answer.

Comment: I HAVE DONE THAT

Answer (score 0):

Make your dynamically EditText on TableLayout, then access it by its row.

Idk, sth like this maybe

```
String[] value = new String[YOUR-COURSE-NUMBER];
for (int i = 0; i < YOUR-COURSE-NUMBER; i++) {
    TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) yourTableLayout.getChildAt(i);
    EditText yourET = (EditText) tableRow.getChildAt(0);
    value[i]= yourET.getText().toString();
}
```